# Is it possible to determine which instance of a class the current instance of a class is instantiated from?

Tags: c#

As the title suggests, it is possible to determine which instance of a class a particular instance of another class is instantiated from?

Update: Example Code below

```
class FooBar: Foo
{
    private Context context;
    public FooBar(Context _context): base(_context)
    {
        this.context = _context;
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public Baz baz;
    private Context context; 
    public Foo(Context _context)
    {
        baz = new Baz();
        this.context = _context;
    }
}

class Baz
{
    public Baz()
    {
        GetNameOfCaller()
    }

    private void GetNameOfCaller()
    {
       ....
       ....
       _className = ....;
    }
    private string _className;
}
```

Comment: Which class the current class? You mean current _instance_, don't you?

Comment: What's the context here? Are you the author of all of the code or just some of it? What will you *do* with this information? Do you need to know at the instant of instantiation or at a later point in time?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes sorry i mean current instance

Comment: @TimSchmelter Actually what i wrote is also correct, isnt it?

Comment: Do you need to know the name of the class, the name of the method, or the actual instance of that class that's instantiating your object? Without more context, I'd recommend to pass such information as an argument to your object's constructor.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Logging purposes for now but may not be limited to it alone. I am the author but i dont think it should limit its contextual purpose, should it? Is there a difference for me to know at the instant of instantiation or at a later time?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I want to know the name of the actual instance of the class that's instantiating the object. Patricks answer below is the solution i am looking for

Comment: @CJC: probably nitpicking since we know what you mean but a class is not an instance so it was not instantiated, an instance of a class was instantiated.

Comment: @CJC: Patricks answer gives you the name of the calling method (or property), not the name of the class.

Comment: @TimSchmelter right again. Let me edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`System.Diagnostics.StackTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
public class Foo 
{
    public void MethodBah()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.StackTrace t = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
        MethodBase callingMethod = t.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
        Type callingMethodType = callingMethod.DeclaringType;
        string className = callingMethodType.Name;
    }
}
```

Works even in .NET 1.1.

---

With your (updated) example you have to use `t.GetFrame(2).GetMethod()` instead of `GetFrame(1)` to get `FooBar` instead of `Foo` because the child- calls the parent constructor.

Comment: In fact it is the better one @CJC since it gives you the class name too. If you don't need that, and you don't use reflection, my answer will suit you.

Comment: @PatrickHofman ok you are right, this is the correct answer, i plugged in your suggestion and all i got is .ctor. So now i am super confused as to what this means.

Comment: You are calling my code from another constructor. The method name for a constructor is `.ctor`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter great it works, but it is giving me the name of the base class, how do i get it to give me the name of the derived class?

Comment: You can't as far as I know.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Ahhh i see, it can only tell me the method name from which it was called from. Well thats also interesting to know. Thank you. Unfortunately I will have to give the correct answer to Tim. But how do i get derived class name of that?

Comment: @CJC: [`MethodBase.DeclaringType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee432914.aspx) gives you the class that declares the current method(so calling method in this case). It will not give you the parent-type (like `Form`) but the actual type of the current instance (f.e. `Form1`). So i don't understand your question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter From the code I see that it is the name of the base class that is in the string _className_ . I have FooBar Class, which derives from Foo class. I new FooBar, but it is the constructor in Foo class that news Baz class. But is it possible to get the name of FooBar class in this case?

Comment: @CJC: would be great to see your code in your question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Just added. Suggestions?

Comment: @CJC: you can get it if you use `t.GetFrame(2).GetMethod()` instead of `t.GetFrame(1).GetMethod()`. But of course that works only here because the derived constructor calls the parent constructor. It is not a reliable way, there is none.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you. I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do that for constructors the same way as for regular methods. Just use the `CallerMemberName` to pass in the name of the calling method. You won't have the class name with it, then you need to walk the `StackTrace` which is much more complicated.

```
public class X
{
    public X([CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
    {
        this.Caller = caller;
    }

    public string Caller { get; private set; }
}
```

Then just call this. The compiler will fill in the `caller` parameter for you:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    X x = new X();
    Console.WriteLine($"Caller = {x.Caller}"); // prints Main
}
```

Comment: `var foo = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(X), "boo")`? I'd not rely on `[CallerMemberName]`.

Comment: And your point is? If you pass in a custom value for `caller`, it is on you.

Comment: @Dennis `var foo = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(X), nameof(Main));`

Comment: Do you have another solution?

Comment: Champion. This seems to be the new way to do things in .Net 4.5. Thank you

Comment: Nope. AFAIK, in general, there is no *reliable* way to do, what OP wants. `[CallerMemberName]` is not a reliable way, of course (while it could be used somewhere in internal APIs).

Comment: So what is wrong with this solution then? If it is the only way to do this semi-reliable, and it suits OPs needs, why not use it then? (Not flaming, I just don't understand why one wouldn't use it, besides reflection, etc)

Comment: Have I said, that OP must not use it? I've said, that this way is not reliable. Just to show OP, that it must be used carefully.

Comment: Okay, agree. Guess you weren't the down-voter. I am not sure why this would be down-voted as it is the only possible way... Thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW I don't understand why knowing the callers gives you from what class was other class instantiated from...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer clarified.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer even if you were, you are free to do so :)

Comment: @Dennis do you find the new `nameof` keyword scary as well?

Comment: I guess his point is "you can fiddle with it". If you accept that, it is a decent solution.

Comment: @Gusdor: since your question is a pure provocation, I'll avoid answering. :) Patrick has got my point well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your requirement should be solved using [aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

OP said in some comment:

> [..] Logging purposes for now but may not be limited to it alone [...]

For example, there's an extremely powerful tool called [*PostSharp*](https://www.postsharp.net/) which lets you intercept any method call, when it's being called and after it was called:

```
[Serializable]
public class LogAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
    }
}
```

Now you can apply the whole aspect as a regular attribute to a method, class or even to an assembly (thus, all methods within the assembly will be *loggable*).

You can access called method through `MethodExecutionArgs.Method` (which is of type [`MethodBase`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29c267yf), and this means that you can access which type declares the whole method through [`MethodBase.DeclaringType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype).

With a tool like PostSharp you are adding an extra compilation step, but it has the great advantage that your interceptions are injected during compile-time. That is, it will perform like adding the whole code manually in every method.

You can also implement the same thing creating run-time proxies using [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) to intercept method calls.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent suggestion. I just had a read about postSharp, i am giving it a try right now.

Comment: @CJC It seems like you're in the right way. Obviously I'm not selling PostSharp, I just used like you in some projects and it's really useful.